Confusion about Ramsey number
Consider R(n,m). It says that within R(n,m) nodes, we can find an n-sided clique of red colored edge or m-sided clique of blue colored edge. If interpreted differently, it may also mean that we can find an n-sided clique of blue colored edge or m-sided clique of red colored edge.
Now combining the two, it means that the within R(n,m) nodes, we can find an n-sided clique of red or blue color or an m-sided clique of red or blue color! But that is R(n,n) or R(m,m).
I know I somewhere misinterpreted it, but cannot clearly see where?
Add: I followed the above from the equality, R(n,m) = R(m,n).

It may help to rephrase it in terms of asking what the largest clique of each color is.

I understand your confusion, as while it is true that $R(n,m)=R(m,n)$, we cannot quite relate them to $R(n,n)$ or $R(m,m)$ as you would like to.
Consider the following example with $n=2$ and $m=4$. It is well known that $R(2,2)=2$ and $R(4,4)=18$ (the former equality is straightforward while the latter equality requires a bit more work to show). However, we claim that $R(2,4)=4$.
On three nodes, we can color all three edges blue, so we know there exists an edge coloring of three nodes with no 2-sided clique of red edges or 4-sided clique of blue edges. This tells us that $R(2,4) > 3$. However, on four nodes, we either have that every edge is blue (in which case we have a 4-sided clique of blue edges) or that at least one edge is red, so we have a 2-sided clique of red edges. Thus, $R(2,4)=4$.
The key here is that on three nodes, although we had a 2-sided clique of blue edges, we did not have a 4-sided clique of blue edges or a 2-sided clique of red edges, which is what we are looking for, hence why we could conclude that $R(2,4)>3$, despite the fact that $R(2,2)=2$.

Let $n\leq m$.
You are correct by saying the Ramsey definition implies that a graph of size $R(n, m)$ will have a monochromatic $n$-clique or a monochromatic $m$-clique. But since finding a monochromatic $m$-clique implies finding a monochromatic $n$-clique, this statement is equivalent to the fact we can find a monochromatic $n$-clique.
However, it does not say that $K(m, n) = K(n, n)$ but only that $K(m, n) \geq K(n, n)$ since a graph smaller than $K(m, n)$ could be sufficient to guarantee a monochromatic $n$-clique.
